# Netbeans: How do i run a project step by step so I can see where the logical error is?

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans

I remember one of my tutors in University, running a project in Netbeans step by step, manually going through each step of the run time. Anyone have any idea how to do this? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: By adding breakpoints in your code, and running the debugger

Comment: Just check this link: https://netbeans.org/features/java/debugger.html

Comment: U r required to debug your application.

Comment: Check the chapter "Debugging Applications" in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50453_01/doc.80/e50452/run_debug_japps.htm#BABFIEHC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to add breakpoints to your code by clicking on the line number like shown on the image below:

[image]

Once you do that you can start you application in debug mode. You do this by clicking the debug button. And the your program will stop at specified debug points. Here is the image of the debug button:

[image]

You can get more information here:
https://netbeans.org/features/java/debugger.html

Comment: Thank you, I suspected it was something to do with the debugger, but I didn't know about the breakpoints thing.

Comment: I will, I just have to wait until i can, 1 minute then i can

Comment: Debugging (with or without a debugger) should be learned by everyone a little after they've managed "Hello, world!".

Comment: Thank you for your very unhelpful comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Once you place a breakpoint you can continue from there either step by step or even using commands to get into a function and move to the code executed by it. You can see a list of your options in the Debug menu:

> F8 - Step Over
>
> F7 - Step Into
>
> Ctrl + F7 - Step out

And so forth. This way you can navigate step by step without the need to have a breakpoint at each step.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I will try it out and see how it works.

Comment: You are welcome. Check the Debug menu, there are few more commands there that you can use then test them out to get more familiar with what they do